# i have added pluginggroup in system.xml maven but running project with mvn clean sonar:sonar gives this error

Tags: sonarqube

Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar (default-cli) on project demo-1: No quality profiles have been found, you probably don't have any language plugin installed.

Comment: well do you have a language plugin installed on your sonarqube server ?

Comment: Have you already followed the steps mentioned in [fixing-missing-language-plugin-issue-in-sonar](https://coderwall.com/p/7wmv-w/fixing-missing-language-plugin-issue-in-sonar)

Comment: no ,i dont know how to install plugin on sonarqube server

Comment: FYI @BobbySharma: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+a+Plugin